# What should we consider when visually evaluating non-stationary data before making assertions?

Tags: time-series, data-visualization, stationarity

I often see charts displaying multiple time series plotted together and they are often accompanied by explanations relating one series to the other. For example, in the below chart, one might say less unemployment leads to more car sales.

I understand these logical relationships are meaningful. However, when I see one or both series has identifiable patterns like seasonality, exponential growth, or has changing variance over time, my brain jumps to thinking it is non-stationary and that the visual relationship might not be statistically significant.

How, if at all, should that thought influence my thinking, like:

a) If I see non-stationary patterns in one or both series, does/ should that disqualify any logical conclusions between the two series?

b) If I want to make conclusions of the series relationship -- based only on visuals -- should I only plot series that are transformed to be stationary first?

**A toy example**:
Pulling from FRED, Unemployment Rate and Auto Sales

```
from fredapi import Fred
s1 = fred.get_series('UNRATE', observation_start='2020-01-01')
s2 = fred.get_series('TOTALSA', observation_start='2020-01-01')
pd.concat([s1,s2], axis=1).plot()

# adfuller for simplicity
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import (adfuller)
adfuller(s1)[1]
# 0.2951
adfuller(s2)[1]
# 0.0019
```

[image: time series plot of unemployment rate and total auto sales from 2020-01 onwards]

Comment: What sort of assertions are you considering?

Comment: @Galen good question, I was originally thinking of anything relating one series to the other like "when X then Y" or "since X has, then Y will"

Comment: I now realize the headline question might benefit from an edit about 'multiple time series data' or something like that..